# MySQL Workbench won't allow me to create foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a few tables and one of them has should have foreign keys referencing the other tables, but MySQL Workbench keeps giving me "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint". This happens if I try to create them during the table creation and if I just create the table and then try to add FK through ALTER. I just can't figure out the problem. I've tried both with and without ENGINE = InnoDB that I saw some people suggest on the web. And yes, tables kommune and person has been created.

```
CREATE TABLE kommune (
Kommunenr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Kommunenavn varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Kommunenr));

CREATE TABLE person (
PersonID varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Fornavn varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Etternavn varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Postnr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Poststed varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PersonID));

CREATE TABLE oppdrag (
Oppdragsnr varchar(5) NOT NULL,
Eiendomnr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Gateadresse varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Postnr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Poststed varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Kommunenr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Prisantydning varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Solgt boolean NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Oppdragsnr),
FOREIGN KEY (Postnr) REFERENCES person(Postnr),
FOREIGN KEY (Poststed) REFERENCES person(Poststed),
FOREIGN KEY (Kommunenr) REFERENCES kommune(Kommunenr));
```

Comment: just create table and after that from structure just set relation between those table as you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the following lines:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Postnr) REFERENCES person(Postnr),
FOREIGN KEY (Poststed) REFERENCES person(Poststed),
```

but in your table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
PersonID varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Fornavn varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Etternavn varchar(45) NOT NULL,
Postnr varchar(4) NOT NULL,
Poststed varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PersonID));
```

`Postnr, Poststed` are neither `unique` or not `primary key`. To make foreign key, the referring column in the base table must be an **indexed column**

Comment: That seems to have been the problem, yes. I put Unique on Postnr and Poststed and it went through.